# Cast IMap to Java Map

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

Is there any way to cast HazelCast `IMap` to `java.util.map(HashMap)`?

```
IMap<K, V> imap = ...;
Map<K, V> map;
```

Didn't find any library method to do so. One way is forming the `Map` using `entrySet` of `IMap` but that includes iterating over complete entrySet and may slow down for huge `IMap`s.

Comment: Does it have to be a `HashMap` specifically? Because `IMap` implements `java.util.Map` already.

Comment: Could you also please add what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

IMap derives from ConcurrentMap. So you can cast it as below

```
IMap<String,String> hzMap = hazelcastInstance.getMap("foo");

Map<String,String> javaMap = hzMap;
ConcurrentMap<String,String> concurrentMap = hzMap;
```